# nginx redirect .php URIs to friendly counterpart

Tags: linux, redirect, nginx

I'm currently using a rewrite to accept requests for files without including the .php extension, however, I can't find out how to have the requests with .php either be denied or redirected to the friendly version.

For example, this is what I want to accomplish:
/contact.php REDIRECT /contact
/contact.php (/contact.php exists, but only accessible via /contact) would result in a 403 error

Current config:

```
location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ @extensionless-php;
index index.php;
}

location ~ .php {
try_files $uri =404;
fastcgi_pass backend;
fastcgi_index index.php;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
include fastcgi_params;
}

location @extensionless-php {
rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
}
```

Comment: Hi, while I understand that you want to redirect to your php files, php is not  involved or related in order to achieve your desired functionality, please remove the php tag as it isn't relevant :) (Or update your question to contain something of php related)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided that what you have already works, I think what you're looking for is this part:

```
if ($request_uri ~ ^/(.*)\.php$) {  return 301 /$1;  }
```

Or, if you're using query parameters, too:

```
if ($request_uri ~ ^/([^?]*)\.php($|\?)) {  return 301 /$1?$args;  }
```

You should place it within your `\.php$` location (which you should rename from your present `.php`).  Trust me, it's NOT going to generate an infinite loop!

Some more explanation was provided in https://serverfault.com/questions/568569/nginx-url-rewrite-rule/568902#568902.