# nginx php friendly URL redirection without interfering with index.php causing /index

Tags: php, redirect, nginx

I've tried so many different configurations to enable permanent redirection of any request ending with .php to redirect to itself without .php.

The issue is, I can't get a rule to redirect requests made to any directory with /index.php to redirect to / instead of /index.

Example:

Desired behavior = /blog/index.php -> /blog/
Current behavior = /blog/index.php -> /blog/index

Is there a clean solution to have any request containing "index.php" to remove itself from the request to simply /, all while still removing .php from all other requests not including index.php?

The two problem lines I can't get to function as desired:

```
if ($request_uri ~* "^(.*/)index\.php$") { return 301 $1; }
if ($request_uri ~ ^/(.*)\.php$) { return 301 /$1; }
```

Config:

```
# Upstream
upstream backend {
server unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}

server {
listen 443 ssl;
server_name mysite.net;

# Serving
root /var/www/html/mysite;
charset utf-8;
index index.php;

# Resources
location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ @extensionless-php;
}

location @extensionless-php {
rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
}

location ~* /includes/(.+)\.php$ {
deny all;
}

location ~ \.php {
try_files $uri =404;
fastcgi_pass backend;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
include fastcgi_params;
}

# Status
location /nginx_status {
stub_status on;
access_log off;
allow 127.0.0.1;
deny all;
}

}
```

Comment: I'd recommend posting what you have currently/attempted so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're likely experiencing the issue with your browser having your prior `301 Moved Permanently` redirects in its cache, thus some of your newer code would not be having any effect.

Clear the cache, and try something like this:

```
index index.php;
if ($request_uri ~ ^/([^?]*?)(?:(?<=/)index(?:\.php)?|\.php)(\?.*)?$) { return 301 /$1$2;   }
```

The above line supports stripping out not only `index.php`, but also [just `index` as you might have from your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32962965/nginx-redirect-php-uris-to-friendly-counterpart/32965758#32965758), as well as just `.php`, yet it preserves the possible query string from `$args`, too.

To avoid having support for stripping just `index`, still supporting the rest of the features as above, use the following instead:

```
if ($request_uri ~ ^/([^?]*?)(?:(?<=/)index)?\.php(\?.*)?$) {   return 301 /$1$2;   }
```

P.S. The original explanation of this trick is here: [nginx redirect loop, remove index.php from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21687288/nginx-redirect-loop-remove-index-php-from-url/21813759#21813759).

Comment: Wow, that is perfect. Thank you. I guess I just didn't really recognize the solution you linked, because I actually saw it when searching around before asking.