# nginx redirect all URI requests with query strings/arguments to the equivalent without

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I was reading around about removing query strings/arguments from all requests by way of redirection like `$1?$argument` to just `$1`.

I tried what the documentation said in adding a `?` to the end of the desired rewrite in order to remove query strings and arguments, but that had no effect.

I wish to maintain current functionality, and remove query strings/arguments from all URI requests.

What is conflicting with the documentation's suggestion of appending `?`, or what is the correct solution for this?

```
# for removing .php from all requests
location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ @extensionless-php;
}

# rewrite to remove .php
location @extensionless-php {
rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
}

# deny access to php includes
location ~* /includes/(.+)\.php$ {
deny all;
}

# redirect all instances of index.php to / in its respective directory (for example, /index.php to /, and /articles/index.php to /articles/)
location ~* \.php {
try_files $uri =404;
if ($request_uri ~ ^/([^?]*?)(?:(?<=/)index(?:\.php)?|\.php)(\?.*)?$) { return 301 /$1$2; }
fastcgi_pass backend;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you're using my solution from [nginx php friendly URL redirection without interfering with index.php causing /index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33030133/nginx-php-friendly-url-redirection-without-interfering-with-index-php-causing-i/33051167#33051167)! :-)

If you also want to get rid of the whole [`$args`](http://nginx.org/r/$args) / [`$query_string`](http://nginx.org/r/$query_string), in addition to removing `index` and `.php`, then just omit the `$2` from the provided solutions; also, you can have an extra if-condition for removing the args from the rest of your URLs, too.

```
index index.php;
if ($request_uri ~ ^/([^?]*?)(?:(?<=/)index(?:\.php)?|\.php)(\?.*)?$) { return 301 /$1; }
if ($request_uri ~ ^/([^?]*)\?) {   return 301 /$1; }
```